# Need a generic term for "model types" and "platforms"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

We are a team of 2 developing a web application. It allows scientists to upload files with measurement data. My question is about how we should name one kind of metadata.

An uploaded file might be the output of some measurement instrument or some scientific model. Both types are connected to some higher level element:

- *instruments* are loaded onto *platforms* which might be ships or airplanes transporting them during the measurement
- *models* are distinguished by their *model type*

Now we'll have lists and database tables with both of them. The lower level element we call *data source* because it's just the very entity producing the data.

Can you think of any reasonable name for something which might be a *platform* or a *model type*?

Comment: Why downvoted? I may improve question as you like if you'd comment what's wrong in your opinion.

Comment: Wasn't me who downvoted, but my guess it's because this can strike the reader as off-topic. Have you read [this part of the FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)?

Comment: I closevoted because it's too localised. This is just another case where someone with a particular app in mind wants a single word to encompass two or more entities which are normally disparate to most native speakers. ELU shouldn't be treated as a "name that function/variable" service.

Answer (score 1):

Because *platform* and *model type* are not obviously parallel in class or meaning, there may be no perfectly suitable word to use as the heading for a platform-or-model-type-specification column.   Generically, *subcategory* may be as accurate as one can get.

Some of the terms italicized below may suggest applicable headings.

- *carrier* - A platform or a model-type is like a *medium* or *modality* or *milieu* or *deliverer* for an instrument or model.
- *genus, species, taxon* - Some variation of biological classification *schema* may work
- *class, category, genre*; and *sub-* forms of same
- *device, mechanism*

Comment: *Category* is what we've in planning until now. Nice suggestions! I'll discuss that with my coworker. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

**Supertype** comes to mind but as jwpat7 said the two aren't analogous, so any one word is going to be necessarily vague.